Spring: How to rollback in a @TransactionalEventListener of phase BEFORE_COMMIT
In Spring Boot 3.x I have transactional-event-listeners. One is bound to phase "BEFORE_COMMIT" and responsible for doing some "last millisecond checks" before the transaction finally commits towards the database:
@TransactionalEventListener(
        phase = TransactionPhase.BEFORE_COMMIT,
        fallbackExecution = true)
public void processPreCommit(MyPreEvent event) {...}

If this check fails, then I need to rollback the transaction. Unfortunately, non of my actions has any affect on the ongoing transaction. I know this, because I also have an "AFTER_COMMIT" transaction listener which should only run in case of a successfully completed transaction but is also executed in case I rollback within the BEFORE_COMMIT transaction listener:
@TransactionalEventListener(
        phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT,
        fallbackExecution = true)
public void processPostCommit(MyPostEvent event) {...}

Rolling back is not that easy within a BEFORE_COMMIT transaction listener. Typically this is done by
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();

In the context of the listener the TransactionAspectSupport does not work any more, so I passed the method setRoolbackOnly into the event and run it within the event listener. This runs without an error but does not rollback the transaction:
// on sending the event within the transaction:
final var tx = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();
publisher.publishEvent(new MyPreEvent(tx::setRollbackOnly));
...
// in the BEFORE_COMMIT transaction listener:
if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
  event.setRollbackOnly.run();
}

Has anyone an idea how to rollback in that special situation?
Thx, Stephan

Another try using the PlatformTransactionManager (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/programmatic.html#transaction-programmatic-ptm) also neither triggered the rollback nor gave an error.
There is also the hint at https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListener.html that transactional resources may not reflect the current transaction status.
However, I managed to trigger a rollback by throwing an exception in the respective transactional event handler.
The only disadvantage in my situation is to get a stacktrace of that exception in the log. In my original implementation only a single log-line was created which would be sufficient.
